# Schedule execution of solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm working on solidity 0.8.13 and I need to schedule a smart contract to run.
I need to run it a few weeks or three months from now.
Also I need to test it in local environment.
Has anyone done it before? I've already seen Chainlink's documentation, but the thing is, I need to do this for a university project, so I don't think it's suitable for my project.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solidity contracts are reactional. You can invoke the code by sending a (read-write) transaction or a (read-only) call to the contract address - but the contract can't be scheduled by itself.

Having said that, you can schedule an offchain code to send a transaction that invokes the contract at specified times. That's essentially what Chainlink Automation and other services do.

Example:

```
async function run() {
    // assuming your app has initialized the `myContract` helper object
    // and knows the private key to the sender address
    myContract.methods.foo().send({from: "0x123"});
}

const ONE_WEEK_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
setInterval(run, ONE_WEEK_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

You can use packages like [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3), [ethers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethers), [brownie](https://pypi.org/project/eth-brownie/), and others to interact with a contract by sending a transaction from an offchain app.